# CSS - <UL> containing variable width <LI>

Tags: html, css, list

Is it possible to have each `<li>` resize its width based upon its content within the same `<ul>`?

It seems that every `<li>` is inherently stretched the match the largest width. How can I avoid this?

The `<ul>` is a vertical list with content varying between pictures and text.

Comment: what you have tried?show some code....

Comment: Is there text/content you want to be next to the <li> or a background you don't want seen all the way across the LI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inline-block is good, but presumably you still want the list items to stack without having to restyle them. In that case you can put the content inside a span or div and set that to inline style.

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><span>test</span></li>
        <li><span>long test</span></li>
        <li><span>longest test</span></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>​
```

with this css

```
li span
{

    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;

}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WHSpW/

Comment: ben, this is working brilliantly with regards to resizing, so thank you! That being said, they no longer stay in a vertical list. Any ideas?

Comment: the key is to set the span to inline-block rather than the li.  If you leave the li alone it should work as it does in the fiddle.

Comment: i just threw an auto `<br/>` at the end of each li and it did the trick. thanks again, great help!

Answer (score 2):

If you set "display" style of `<li>` to inline-block it should work as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you float them they will take on the width of the content they contain.

```
li {float: left;}
```

You'll want to either float the containing `ul` or apply a [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) to keep it from collapsing. Under IE6 you can use zoom:1 to trigger hasLayout on the `ul`.